# Heading title with a logo

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to lay out the following:

```
XXXXXXX Title
XXXXXXX Subtitle
XXXXXXX Maybe even a date!
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX


Content, content, content ...
```

The X's are an image (a logo), and the text is just off to the side. This is sort of a title to a page - not a float, so figures and captions seem wholly inappropriate: this needs to be rendered where it appears in the text, which will be kind of the top of the file. `\maketitle` is just too bulky, and this should have a more branded feel.

```
\begin{document}
% What goes here?
\includegraphics{the_logo.pdf}
Title \\ Subtitle \\ Maybe even a date!
% </what goes here>

Content, content, content...
\end{document}
```

I appreciate that LaTeX generally handles formatting for me, but on the occasions I want to take control of the layout, it seems next to impossible...

Comment: Is your problem with the position and/or size of the text?  I would try using the graphpap package.  It will allow you to create a sort of grid so that you can put objects at the exact coordinates that you specify.

Comment: @Kirsten: Position mostly. I would like Tex to figure out where to put the text, given the size of the image and all. I tried tables, but couldn't figure out how to get vertical alignment or line breaks in it. I tried frames and boxes, but can't figure out line breaks.

Comment: Since you’re death, … SHOULDN’T YOU BE SPEAKING IN CAPITALS?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, LMAO! (BTW, smallcaps, actually, hence the attraction to TeX `;)` ).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- A tabular environment, parboxes or minipages could be used.
- Specify an alignment option, for `\parbox` and `minipage` choose `[t]`.
- To avoid alignment problems (`\includegraphics` sets the baseline to the bottom of the picture) insert `\vspace{0pt}` before `\includegraphics`.
- The same trick helps with the aligment of a text line, so you might need it in a second minipage too.
- Be careful with boxes or minipages when trying to fit the text width, use % to avoid additional space in the output because of a line break acting like whitespace.

Here's a small example showing how you could start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\LARGE \textbf{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\mysubtitle}[1]{\large\textbf{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\mydate}[1]{\small #1\par}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{test}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\mytitle{Title}
\mysubtitle{Subtitle}
\mydate{\today}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\noindent Content, content, content ...
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is closer than I've ever gotten. Is there a way to use the minipage without having to specify the width? I'd like the minipages to shrink to the content, ideally. I can shrinkwarp the left (logo) minipage with `\settowidth` on the image... is there some way to do `\textwidth - \mylogowidth` (where `\mylogowidth` is a length of the logo's width?)

Comment: Actually, found `\addtolength` (is there a subtract?) and multiplied what I was subtracting by -1. Looks pretty good now, and doesn't rely on any magic numbers. Thanks!

Comment: @Enos Ask a new question, do not hijak other answers!