# Need Help to include personal details in make heading

Tags: titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Heading title with a logo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5284/heading-title-with-a-logo)

I would like to ask you how to create the makeheading in such a way that, my name and personal details are beside of my Photo. I need as follows

============================================================

## NAME      --------------------------                                            PHOTO

## Date of Birth  -----------------                                       PHOTO

## Nationality    --------------------                              PHOTO

Here i wanna start the contact information.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With what document class are you working with? You should add a compilable example... If you just want to wrap the figure, you can to that with a simple `minipage` environment in any class...

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Required to include the figure
 \begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
   Name: Lorem Ipsum \\
   Date of Birth: 01/01/2011 \\
   nationality: Nowhere \\
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{/path/to/figure}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Actually there are related questions with better answers than mine. See: [this question: "Heading title with a logo"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5284/heading-title-with-a-logo)