# Figure next to the \maketitle

Tags: minipage

I tried a picture next to the \maketitle like in this [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5284/heading-title-with-a-logo) But I make bigger the size of picture and the title is hidden behind the picture. What should I edit? Next problem is that I have only black rectangle instead of picture. How to add a picture? I thought that `\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=5.503cm,height=4.654cm]{m.png}` last braces is a name of picture. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\LARGE \textbf{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\mysubtitle}[1]{\large\textbf{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\mydate}[1]{\small #1\par}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=5.503cm,height=4.654cm]{m.png}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}
\vspace{20pt}
\mytitle{Title}
\mydate{\today}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the black rectangle is because you have `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`  remove demo,  for the rest remove `[width=5.503cm,height=4.654cm` (which would distort the image) just specify `[width=\linewidth]` so the image scales to fit.

Comment: Thank you and how to set a space between figure and title? Or how to get figure to the right side of the page?

Comment: you have made two minipage with no space between them adding up to textwidth, if you want a space change the width from `.3\textwidth` to (say) `.25\textwidth` and change `\end{minipage}%` to `\end{minipage}\hfill` to put hfill space betwween the minipages

Comment: I added a picture to my question, do we mean the same space?

Comment: yes if you want a gap you need to make one of the minpage smaller, I suggested reducing the image, you could of course reduce the size of the second minipage with the title text instead.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that, what I tried was wrong. Or maybe it would be better give a title to left and figure to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I noted the changes in code comments below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\LARGE \textbf{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\mysubtitle}[1]{\large\textbf{#1}\par}
\newcommand{\mydate}[1]{\small #1\par}
% just rectangles \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\noindent%
%.3+.7 leaves no gap
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
%%%%% height and width distorts \includegraphics[width=5.503cm,height=4.654cm]{m.png}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % space between the minipages
\begin{minipage}[t]{.65\textwidth}
\vspace{20pt}
\mytitle{Title}
\mydate{\today}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```